# how to trigger selectize input to make options shown initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize, and I want to show a few options without clicking selectize input. So I use `$('.selectize-input').click()` but it doesn't work. How to show a few options without clicking input?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you bind selectize plugin something like `$('.selectize-input').selectize(options)`, you should be able to use API's [open](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) method like this:

```
$('.selectize-input')[0].open();
```