# Showing dropdown options in selectizeInput with shinyjs / javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

In my app, I have a search bar, which filters the options in a related selectizeInput. When a user types something into the search bar and clicks the search icon / presses enter, I want the choices in the below dropdown to be shown (similar to if I had clicked on the selectizeInput), so it's clear to the user that their search was processed.

I was able to use this [post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/selectizeinput-id-is-null/9387) to figure out how to reference the dropdown from JavaScript. However, I am struggling to write the JS code needed to expand the dropdown.

I have tried the .click method, and have tried using the selectize API method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687392/how-to-trigger-selectize-input-to-make-options-shown-initially) and [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md). However, the code provided in the latter examples is so minimal that I can't seem to replicate it.

I have pasted a MWE below. I would prefer to use the selectize API method but I am open to any Javascript method that will simulate "clicking and expanding" the below dropdown when a search is entered. This is my first time posting on SO, so I apologize if I have missed anything! Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

    useShinyjs(),  # Include shinyjs
    
    #the search bar that will hopefully open the below dropdown when the user clicks "enter"
    searchInput(
      inputId = "search_box", label = "Search", placeholder = "",
      btnSearch = icon("search"), btnReset = NULL),
    
    selectizeInput("dropdown","Select from dropdown", multiple = T,
                   choices = c("dog 1","dog 2","dog 3","cat 1","cat 2","cat 3")),
    
    #accessing the selectize input with javascript
    actionButton("access_selectize","Access selectize with js")
    
    
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    #confirming that element is properly accessed with JS
    observeEvent(input$access_selectize,{
        runjs('alert($("#dropdown :selected").text())')
    })
    
    #this part does not work... 
    observeEvent(input$search_box, {
        runjs('
        var $select = $("#dropdown :selected").selectize(options);
        $select[0].open();
        ')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```